# Using Perl in-line edits, how do you insert a line after the Nth occurence of a string?

Tags: regex, perl, scripting

Looking for a method to insert a line after the Nth occurence of a given string.

The following is close to what I'm looking for, but is line number based, versus based on the Nth occurrence of a given string.

```
perl -ni -e 'print; print "Put after fifth line\n" if $. == 5' inFile.txt
```

Comment: can a line have multiple occurrence of the string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following will add a line of `xyz` after the second occurrence of the string `abc`:

```
perl -pi -e '/abc/&&++$n==2 and $_.="xyz\n"' inFile.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

No need to initialize the count if warnings aren't enabled.

```
perl -pe'$_.="foo\n" if /bar/ && ++$c == 5'
```

The modulus (`%`) operator is great for detecting every Nth.

```
perl -pe'$_.="foo\n" if /bar/ && ++$c % 5 == 0'
```

Answer (score 2):

[*It's always nice to see someone checked the FAQ! [How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change%2c-delete%2c-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file%2c-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file%3f).*]

Here's how I would do it:

```
% perl -ni -e 'print; print "Inserted\n" if (/time/ && ++$c) == 3' input.txt
```

The counter variable `$c` is incremented by the return value of the match operator. It's 0 if it doesn't match and 1 if it does match (it's used in scalar context so even with a `/g` it only matches once at most). After that update to `$c` it's compared to the value you want.

Here's *input.txt*:

```
 First time
 Second time
 Third time
 Fourth time
```

And the result:

```
 First time
 Second time
 Third time
 Inserted
 Fourth time
```

Alternately, you make make this a little shorter with `-p` which automatically puts a `print` at the end. In that case you end up inserting the line *before* the next line instead of *after* the previous line (and that may be a problem if you don't have enough lines to come before something):

```
% perl -pi -e 'print "Inserted\n" if (/time/ && ++$c) == 4' input.txt
```

And, you might consider upgrading to v5.28 if you are not using it already. [In-place editing gets a bit safer](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2017/12/in-place-editing-gets-safer-in-v5-28/)  by writing to a temp file first then replacing the source file once the program completes successfully.

Comment: counter should be reset (or condition shouldn't be checked altogether once it is satisfied, depending on requirement) ... otherwise this will continue to print `Inserted` until counter changes.. for example, remove `time` from `Fourth time` line..

Comment: if the 4th line is removed and the script as shown, the insert occurs before the 3rd line instead of after.   ???


perl -pi -e 'print "Inserted\n" if (/\ time/ && ++$c) == 3' input.txt

Comment: If you are using `-p` the output of the current line comes after the insertion. That's why I changed the number to be one larger in the second one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to repeat after every fifth occurrence of the string, you can create a variable in a `BEGIN` block and monitor it:

```
perl -n -e 'BEGIN{$c=0;} print; $c++ if /one/; if ($c==5){print "Put after fifth entry\n";$c=0}' inFile.txt
```